# PostMessage() не доходит до цели, если отправлять его из бесконечного цикла в параллельном потоке

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, ipc

Учебная задача. Нужно использовать именно сообщения.

Нужно сделать две программы, обменивающиеся данными через сообщения. Первая получает сообщение в духе "Start", после чего начинает каждые 5 секунд отправлять второму "Ask value". Второе в ответ шлёт "Send value" с какими-то данными.

Первая программа (проект WinForms):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Oven_Monitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        private uint askMessageID      = RegisterWindowMessage("Ask value");
        private uint dataMessageID     = RegisterWindowMessage("Send value");
        private uint registerMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor");

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Really rare title";
        }

        public void checkSensors() {
            while (true) {
                PostMessage(secondAppHWnd, askMessageID, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private IntPtr secondAppHWnd;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == registerMessageID) {
                secondAppHWnd = m.LParam;
                Thread tr = new Thread(checkSensors);
                tr.Start();
            } else if (m.Msg == dataMessageID) {
                //do some stuff
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Вторая:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HeatSensor
{
    public partial class HiddenForm : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        static private IntPtr mainAppHandle;

        public HiddenForm(IntPtr mainAppHWnd)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainAppHandle = mainAppHWnd; //получаю извне
            string title = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            title += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            title += System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            this.Text = title;
            this.CreateHandle();
            int currentWindowHandle = (int)FindWindow(null, title);
            SendMessage(mainAppHandle, RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor"),
                (UIntPtr)0, currentWindowHandle);
        }

        private uint askMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Ask value");
        private uint dataMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Send value");
        private uint registerMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("Register sensor");

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == askMessageID)
            {
                SendMessage(mainAppHandle, dataMessageID, (UIntPtr)1, (IntPtr)1);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

`checkSensors()` отправляет сообщение и... вторая программа его не получает (HWnd и wMsg 100% правильные). Если взять эту строчку и вызвать из `WndProc()`, то всё будет работать как надо.

Что может быть не так?

Приведённый код полностью отражает проблемную часть программы и может быть скомпилирован.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, проблема в том, что я пытаюсь таким образом взаимодействовать с консольным приложением (либо следует сделать что-то ещё со скрытой формой).

В итоге, решил сделать 2 программу оконной и всё заработало. Осталось скрыть окно и запустить из него консоль.